# Ajax call to alter MySQL SELECT query

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm working on a web app to keep track of recent expenses. I'd like the user to be able to select 4 different time periods which displays different data. When a user first lands on the page, the "overall" data would show by default. When a range is selected by the user, i'd like to use an ajax call to take the data-range and alter the mysql query. My experience with ajax is low, and i'm curious as to how this would be done.

Here is my HTML (echoed in PHP):

```
echo "<section class='range-container'>" .
         "<ul class='overview-range'>" .
             "<li data-range='overall'>Overall</li>" .
             "<li data-range='$currentYear'>Year</li>" .
             "<li data-range='$currentMonth'>Month</li>" .
             "<li data-range='$currentDay'>Day</li>" .
         "</ul>" .
     "</section>";

include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/ajax/overview.php';
```

The overview.php file: For this example I only have the DAY(date) option in the query.

```
<?php   

if ($_POST['range']) {
    $currentTime = $_POST['range'];
} else {
    $currentTime = '0';
}

//Overview Query
$sqloverview = $db->prepare('SELECT SUM(amount), trans_type
               FROM transactions
               WHERE (amount > 0 AND DAY(date) = :currentTime) OR
               amount > 0
               GROUP BY trans_type
               ORDER BY trans_type DESC');
$sqloverview->execute(array(':currentTime' => sanitizeString($currentTime)));
$overviewRows = $sqloverview->num_rows;

?>
```

And the jQuery file:

```
$('.overview-range li').click(function() {
    var range = $(this).attr('data-range');

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url:  '/ajax/overview.php',
      data: { range: range },
      error: function() { alert("Unable to process this request."); },
      success: function() {
         alert('It was successful');
     }
    });
});
```

Would this be the correct way to go about this process? Or is there a better way other than ajax? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `queryMysql` is a terrifying function to see. What does that wrap around?

Comment: **WARNING**: This has some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because `$_GET` data is used inside the query. Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

**NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly in your query.

Comment: tadman: I updated the query to use pdo statements.

Comment: You've got it almost right. There's no need to "sanitize" something if you're binding it to a placeholder. If anything you'd want to validate that's a correct date and not junk data, but putting in garbage shouldn't be a security problem.